# Validate long number expression

Tags: regex, numbers, expression, long-integer

How can I use Regex expression to validate this number from a textbox: 99-9999-99999999999999-99-999-999999999-9-99999999/9?

Comment: Can you clarify how it's supposed to match? Right now, I see `^(\d+)(-\d+)*/\d+$`, although I suspect the numbers may be fixed width.

Comment: What language?  Are the groups between the dashes specific sizes?  All numbers 0-9?  What have you tried?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer accurately a question without good information.

But I assume every `9` might be any number and the hyphen and slash must be fixed.

For this case you can use this regex:

```
^\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{14}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{9}-\d-\d{8}\/\d$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC1kJ9/1)**

Comment: That's it Federico! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexJC glad to help